# CORS support for a Jersey app with WADL

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, cors, wadl

I have a Java Application in Eclipse. Using Jersey, it successfully creates a webpage locally (localhost).

The problem is I have a javascript on another server trying to access that webpage and it throws a CORS error.

Is there any built-in CORS support for Jersey/WADL applications?

I've tried creating a Jersey filter that supports CORS - following these [instructions](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/09/cors-filter-for-java-applications.html). No luck. :( I'm looking into [this](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html), but am unsure if it is the right choice for what I want to do.

Essentially, my header is currently this:

[image]

But I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Thanks all!

**EDIT:**

As per jgm's suggestion, I have created a filter (called CORSFilter) and added the requesite dependencies. Am I registering the filter correctly in the web.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>createJPA</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Root REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Root REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>model.producer.CORSFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple CORS filter for jersey, adapted from the [Weald Technology utilities](https://github.com/wealdtech/wealdtech):

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import com.wealdtech.jersey.CORSConfiguration;

/**
 * Filter to handle cross-origin resource sharing.
 */
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
  private static final String ACAOHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
  private static final String ACRHHEADER = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
  private static final String ACAHHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
  private static final String ACAMHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
  private static final String ACACHEADER = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";

  private final transient CORSConfiguration configuration;

  @Inject
  public CORSFilter(final CORSConfiguration configuration)
  {
    this.configuration = configuration;
  }

  @Override
  public ContainerResponse filter(final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse response)
  {
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACAOHEADER, this.configuration.getOrigin());

    final String requestHeaders = request.getHeaderValue(ACRHHEADER);
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACAHHEADER, requestHeaders);
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACAMHEADER, this.configuration.getAllowedMethods());
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(ACACHEADER, this.configuration.allowCredentials());

    return response;
  }
}
```

For the configuration you can either [use the existing configuration setup](https://raw.github.com/wealdtech/wealdtech/develop/wealdtech-jersey-server/src/main/java/com/wealdtech/jersey/CORSConfiguration.java) or incorporate it in to your own system.  Note that this uses Google Guice to inject the configuration, if you aren't using Guice you'll need to do this manually.

Comment: I've configured Google Guice. But can't find the jar to resolve "import com.wealdtech.jersey.CORSConfiguration" not being recognized.

Comment: Well the link to the configuration class is in the answer so you can just take it and copy it.  If you want the full JAR it's in maven group com.wealdtech artiface wealdtech-jersey-server

Comment: Okay cool. I added the jar and ran the application. But it hasn't added the header. Maybe the filter isn't associated with the .java file correctly?

Comment: You need to register the filter; how you do that depends on how you're initializing Jersey but there is a Guice module at JerseyServletModule in the wealdtech-jersey-server JAR and there is a test you can see at  https://github.com/wealdtech/wealdtech/blob/develop/wealdtech-jersey-server/src/test/java/test/com/wealdtech/jersey/JerseyTest.java which brings up a server (code is in the setUp() method)

Comment: Sorry I avoid the whole XML configuration stuff like the plague so can't answer that bit.